# Jquery UI slideUp and slideDown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle, slidedown, slideup

I am busy to show and hide some boxes with a click on a button. It is working well but i must click 2 times the first time i want to hide a box?

This is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.title .hide').showContent();
});

$.fn.showContent = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var box = $(this);
        var content = $(this).parent().next('.content');

        box.toggle(function() {
            content.slideDown(400);
        }, function() {
            content.slideUp(400);
        });

    });
};
```

And de HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">
        Title
        <span class="hide"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Why is this? Can somewone help me?

And here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7PF/ (click on the black button. When you click the first time it is doing nothing, but the second time then the content will collapse.)

Comment: @Maanstraat where's the button you speak of in your HTML?

Comment: The button is the span with the class hide: <span class="hide"></span>

Comment: I have made a JSFiddle to: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7PF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse your functions

```
box.toggle(function() {
  content.slideUp(400);
}, function() {
  content.slideDown(400);
});
```